# Solving a functional problem $\min\int_0^1(ay^2+2byy'+cy'^2)\;dx,\;y(0)=0, y(1)=1$

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I have the following problem in my Calculus of Variations course:

> Find all smooth extremums if $a,b$ and $c$ are positive numbers
>
> $$\min\int_0^1(ay^2+2byy'+cy'^2)\;dx,\;y(0)=0, y(1)=1$$

I have tried solving this for few days with the basic techniques by applying the [Euler-Lagrange equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-LagrangeDifferentialEquation.html) but still I get a very hairy calculations which make me start to doubt about the correctness of my solution. I would need a guiding light on this one. How to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Lagrangian

$$L(y,y') = ay^2 + 2byy' + cy'^2$$

the EL equation becomes

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}\implies 2ay + 2by' = \frac{d}{dx}[2by + 2cy']$$

which simplifies (for $c\not = 0$; if $c=0$ then there are no smooth solutions) to

$$y'' = \frac{a}{c}y \implies y(x) = A e^{\omega x} + B e^{-\omega x}$$

where $\omega^2 = a/c$ and $A,B$ are free constants (if $a=0$ the equation to solve becomes $y''=0$). The solution that satsify the boundary condtions $y(0)=0$ and $y(1) = 1$ is

$$y(x) = \frac{e^{\omega x}  -e^{-\omega x}}{e^{\omega} - e^{-\omega}} = \frac{\sinh(\omega x)}{\sinh(\omega)}$$

If $a/c < 0$ then $\omega$ is imaginary. In this case you can use $\sinh(iz) = i\sin(z)$ to write down the solution (if you like to keep it real).

Comment: Thank you =) appreciate it!